# gravity form login widget redirect

Tags: wp-redirect, wp-login-form, plugin-gravity-forms

i placed 'Gravity Forms User Registration Add-On's login widget in a page that registered users can login to my site.
how do i redirect users to previous page that came from to login page after they submit login form?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, support questions for this plugin is off topic. Please contact the plugin author or make use of its support route.

Comment: Hi and thank you. can't you help me solve this issue as this is a wordpress  topic, please

Comment: or show me another way to use a login plugin in custom page, and then redirect them to previous page ??

Comment: Hi, I don't know enough about gravity form to help you. You can try their support: https://www.gravityhelp.com/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution :

```
add_filter('gform_user_registration_login_args','registration_login_args',10, 1);
function registration_login_args( $args )
{ 
$args['login_redirect'] = rgpost('login_redirect') ? rgpost('login_redirect') : RGForms::get('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER);
return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by help of gravity forms documentation i wrote this code , but it doesn't work!

> https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_user_registration_login_redirect_url/

```
function redirect_mylogin ( $login_redirect, $sign_on ) {
//here is redirection code
$login_redirect = esc_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
return $login_redirect; }
add_filter( 'gform_user_registration_login_redirect_url','redirect_mylogin', 10, 2 );
```

please help!